# Multiply point values by raster values

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point

I have a point shapefile containing elevation values in the id field. The shapefile is overlaying a raster layer of the topographical slope. Is it possible to multiply the elevation value of each point by the respective slope value of the raster cell laying immediately below the point?

Comment: Workflow: Convert your point layer to a raster layer of the same extent using the attribute id as cell value. Then use a raster calculator to multiply both rasters. What software are you using?

Comment: Many thanks, Curlew. I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: @Curlew your solution seems computationally expensive compared to just assigning the raster values to the point feature class and multiplying the columns.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the "Arctoolbox > Spatial Analyst Tools > Extraction > Extract Values to Points" to create a new column, in your point featureclass, containing the raster slope values. You would then just create a new column in the point featureclass and populate it by multiplying the elevation and slope columns.